# Observer agreement with Cohen's Kappa - is there a way to combine ratings to investigate if one rating impacts the other

Tags: agreement-statistics, cohens-kappa

I am a medical scientist doing observer agreement analysis on some very simple data using Cohen's Kappa. I have 2 observers. They score a bunch of scans on a 3 point scale for a pattern called honeycombing (definitely present, possibly present, absent). They also score for emphysema on the same 3 point scale. It is commonly believed that observers confuse these patterns. The unweighted kappa for honeycombing is 0.56. The unweighted kappa for emphysema is 0.17.

I need to demonstrate if the emphysema pattern does confuse observers when trying to identify honeycombing and I assumed that if I combine the scores in some way, if this hypothesis is true, the kappa for honeycombing should improve. - i.e combine the scores so that the result represents the observers determination for the present of honeycombing OR emphysema.

I am confused however - when I create a binary score for honeycombing (present/possibly present versus absent) and the same for emphysema and then combine these binary scores to give a "honeycombing or emphysema present or absent" the kappa falls to 0.46. I find this hard to explain. I am a novice to statistics. Opinions appreciated - I am sure its a point of logic I am missing.